# ionic 2 - crash on android 7.1

Tags: android, ionic2

I want run ionic 2 on device with android 7.1 with below steps :

1- ionic start myApp blank --v2

2- ionic platform add android@latest

3- add min and target sdk in config.xml like this :

```
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="18" />
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="25" />
```

4- ionic build android

5 - run output apk file on genymotion simulator (samsung galaxy s6 - 7.1.0 - API 25)

but when install and open application , and after ionic splash page, I see just a white screen

Comment: do you get any console logs?

Comment: console in ionic serve is clear

Comment: no..https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/ use this with device/emulator and debug

Comment: chrome dev tools console also is clean